# I don't understand why my Python code is not running properly

Tags: python, encoding, jupyter

I don't understand why my code in Jupyter Notebook doesn't run correctly when I execute it with "Run All Cells," but if I run the cell individually with Ctrl+Enter, everything is fine.

Real example:

```
df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'] = pd.to_datetime(df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'])
df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'] = df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'].dt.date
df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'] = pd.to_datetime(df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'])
df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'] = df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'] = df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'].astype(str)

df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'] = pd.to_datetime(df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'], errors='coerce')
df_filtrato_sett0 = df_m_dom[df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento'].between(inizio_settimana, fine_settimana)]
```

In "Run All Cells," the DataFrame df_filtrato_sett0 is empty. However, if I rerun the cell individually, it becomes populated. I don't understand; I had to add a for loop and run it three times to make it work.

The same thing happens with this code:

```
df_merged_sett_dom['Variazione_Percentuale'] = np.where((df_merged_sett_dom['Media_8sett'] != 0) | (df_merged_sett_dom['Media_8sett'] != -0),
                                         ((df_merged_sett_dom['Score_point_sett_corr'] - df_merged_sett_dom['Media_8sett']) / df_merged_sett_dom['Media_8sett'].abs()) * 100,
                                         df_merged_sett_dom['Score_point_sett_corr'] * 100)

df_merged_sett_dom['Variazione_Percentuale'] = df_merged_sett_dom['Variazione_Percentuale'].round(0)
df_merged_sett_dom['Media_8sett'] = df_merged_sett_dom['Media_8sett'].round(0)
```

I wouldn't want the code, in general, to be computed incorrectly. It doesn't seem like it, but there is a concern.

Comment: When you say _if I rerun the cell individually_, do you mean **after restarting the runtime** or just after "run all cells"?

Comment: mean that when all cells are executed with 'Run All Cells,' and I re-run the specific cells with 'Ctrl + Enter,' the code works.

Comment: If you run all cells and then re-run then without restarting the runtime, that means you are running each cell twice: i.e. if you have two cells, you are running [1] [2] [1] [2]. `df_m_dom['data/ora stato evento']` is clearly not the same the first time you run cell [1] than the second one. Using "Run all Cells" (or running everything _in order_ twice with `Ctrl +Enter`) should give you the same result.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Its most likely caused by order of the code cells in your jupyter notebook being wrong. There are two things that come to my mind that you could look out for/check:

Cells that modify df_m_dom and df_merged_sett_dom may not be executed in the correct order. If one cell depends on the output of another cell running them out of order may lead to undesired behavior.

When you use pd.to_datetime with errors='coerce', it can result in NaN values for invalid dates causing error in later of the code.